# How to wait looping before execute other code?

Tags: javascript, async-await

i wanna my code can wait a looping before it execute. Says that i have code like this:

```
static getData(num){
    return fetch('https://somedomain.me/${i}')
        .then(resolve => {
            return.resolve.json()
        })
        .then(resolveJson => {
            if(resolveJson.status == 'ok'){
                return Promise.resolve(resolveJson.data);
            } else{
                return Promise.reject('Something Error')
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {return Promise.reject(error)});

}
static async myFunction(){
    const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const content = []
    for(let i in a){
        try{
            const myData = await this.getData(i);
            content.push(myData);
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }

    }
    console.log(content);

}
```

But `console.log(content)` is execute firstly even i use `async-await`. So, i can't get data from `fetch`. Something wrong with myCode?

Edit: `return Promise.resolve(resolveJson)`, `return Promise.reject('Something Error')`, `return Promise.reject(resolveJson)`. and `try-catch`

Comment: `return.resolve.json()` will throw a SyntaxError, and you have no `resolve` function in scope inside `getData`

Comment: just because fetch returns promises doesn't mean there's a `resolve` function ... resolve function only exists inside a Promise constructor

Comment: ... nor `reject`

Comment: Sorry, i m newbie in javascript. but my other project get this problem, but some fetchs executed. i looping fetch 3 times, and the output from console.log: (firstFetch). the second and the third are not obtained. Can anybody tell me what should i do?

Comment: @CertainPerformance @Jaromanda X @Luis Ramalho i return `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject`. And try to `console.log(getData)`, there is the result(not error). Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fetch` with async/await as well:

```js
static async getData(num){
    const result = await fetch('https://somedomain.me/${i}')
    const {data, status} = await result.json()
    if (status === 'ok') {
        return data
    }

    throw new Error('Something error')
}
static async myFunction(){
    const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const content = []
    for(const i of a) {
        const myData = await this.getData(i);
        content.push(myData);
    }
    console.log(content);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But `console.log()` still execute before looping done. some fetch results were got (first and second). the result: `firstFetch, secondFetch, undefined, undefined, undefined`. I think the API is empty or something like that. But i check with postman, there are the data in the API